# How to convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Basically I have the following function where I need to convert `ArrayList` to `List`

```
public List<List<Integer>> somefunc(int[] nums) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    // logic

    return a;
}
```

How can I convert this `ArrayList<ArrayList>` to `List<List>`?

Comment: ArrayList is already a List...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always prefer programming to interfaces.

Change

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

to

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can add `ArrayList<Integer>` instances to `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Write this:

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Or even this:

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to "convert" it.

Just declare your `a` as

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

You can add any `List<Integer>` to your `a`:

```
a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```